# How do I customize a meteor package to use it in my project

Tags: meteor

I am trying to use meteor typeahead package in my project. It has some issues with it, so the developer asked me to create a local PR and use it. The thing is that I don't know how to create a local PR. Do I need to create a local package and then add it to my project, etc.  I cloned the repository to my local machine, and changed the code that I need, but I don't know what to do after this. Can somebody help me with this please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After you cloned the package just copy all the files in a `packages/name_of_the_package` folder of your Meteor project.
You can also create a symbolic link between the package folder and the package folder in the Meteor project. So all changes are automatically reflected.

Then, add it as usual with `meteor add name_of_the_package` or by modifying the `.meteor/packages` file. Meteor will look in priority in the local package folder instead of the official repository.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a fork of the desired repo.
2. Clone your fork of the repo as a sub folder of the "packages" folder within your app.
3. Remove the atmosphere package by performing a `meteor remove some:package`
4. Add the package back, just as you normally would, with `meteor add some:package`. Meteor will find the local copy and use it, instead of downloading the package from Atmosphere.
5. Make the desired code changes, testing it before you commit.
6. Commit your changes to Github.
7. Create a pull request within the fork on Github.